# Шаблонная функция QSort на С++ для работы с итераторами из STL

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl, qsort

Здравствуйте.
Помогите написать на С++ шаблонную функцию быстрой сортировки, которая принимает два итератора и компаратор и работает с итераторами из STL.

Примерно так:

```
template <class Iterator, class Comparator>

void qsort(Iterator first, Iterator last, comparator cmp){ // cmp - функтор
         // тело сортировки
         for(...)
              for(...)
                   if cmp(*first, *last)
                       iter_swap(first, last)
// пример cmp для int
class intcmp{
public:
           bool operator()(int a, int b){
                    return a<b;
           }
};

// Создаём  вектор или массив

#include <vector> 
std::vector<int> a; 
for (i :=0; i<10; i++)
      a.push_back(rand())
qsort(a.begin(), a.end(), intcmp())
--------------( или )--------------
int a[];
 . . .
qsort(a, a+10, intcmp())

// И вывести элементы a[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот по простому набросал.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename _iterator, typename T, typename compare>
void __qsort__(_iterator first, _iterator last, const T& pv, compare cmp){
    T v = *(first + ((last - first)/2));
    _iterator f = first;
    _iterator l = last;

    do {
        while((f < last) && cmp(*f, v))
            ++f;
        while((l > first) && cmp(v, *l))
            --l;

        if(f <= l){
            std::swap(*f, *l);
            ++f;
            --l;
        }
    } while(f <= l);

    if(l > first)
        __qsort__(first, l, v, cmp);
    if(last > f)
        __qsort__(f, last, v, cmp);
}

template<typename _iterator, typename compare>
void qsort(_iterator first, _iterator last, compare cmp){
    if(first < --last)
        __qsort__(first, last, *first, cmp);    
}

template<typename T>
struct compare {
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b){
        return (a < b);
    }
};

int main(void){
    vector<int> vs(10);

    for(vector<int>::iterator i = vs.begin(); i != vs.end(); )
        *i++ = rand() % 10;

    copy(vs.begin(), vs.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    qsort(vs.begin(), vs.end(), compare<int>());

    copy(vs.begin(), vs.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nuklon, спасибо!
Зачем к first прибавлять середину?
T v = *(first + ((last - first)/2));

Comment: @Art Mart, Вас интересует, почему

    f + (l - f) / 2

вместо

    (f + l) / 2

или зачем значение `v` берется из середины интервала?

Первое -- защита от арифметического переполнения 

Второе -- в качестве разделяющего элемента (после цикла разделения слева будут все меньше, а справа все большие его (*собственно, в этом и состоит суть алгоритма quicksort*)) возьмем элемент из середины. 

(Можно брать случайный, можно медиану (средний по значению) из первого, последнего и среднего. 

Между прочим, именно выбор разделяющего элемента во многом определяет эффективность реализации).

Comment: Спасибо) Точно, ведь так алгоритм быстрой сортировки устроен.